# GDS Galileo MIR FILE

Tags: parsing, integration, galileo

I have lots of Galileo MIR files and want to parse the information present in it. I saw a VB Script code available on google code. But is there any other way to achieve this. My aim is to get all the details of segments, PNR, Passenger details etc. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks